# Parallel Processing Speed up S(n)

Tags: performance, parallel-processing

Assume that a query is decomposed into a serial part and a parallel part. The serial part occupies 20% of the entire elapsed time, whereas the rest can be done in parallel.
Given that the one-processor elapsed time is 1 hour, what is the speed up if 10 processors are used? (For simplicity, you may assume that during the parallel processing of the parallel part the task is equally divided among all participating processors).

Comment: Hello. I think https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com is a better place to address your question

Comment: What did you try? This sounds like homework.

Answer (score 0):

Even with `n` processors the serial part will take up the same share (0.2) of computation time as in the one-processor elapsed time (OPELT = 1 hour) scenario. The other 80% can be done in parallel, thus are divided by the number of processors available.

```
0.2*OPELT + (0.8*OPELT)/n
```

Speed up `S(n)` is then the ratio between the one-processor elapsed time and the n-processor elapsed time.

In detail to be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParallelComputing.html).